# Scala Regex pattern-matching in constructor instantiates subclass

Tags: regex, scala, pattern-matching, immutability

I have the following code to do regex pattern-matching.

```
class UserAgent(val ua: String) {
  val iOS = """.*(iPad|iPhone|iPod).*OS ([0-9_]+).*""".r
  val Android = """.*Android ([0-9.]+).*""".r
  val WindowsPhone = """.*Windows Phone OS.*""".r
  val WebOS = """.*webOS.*""".r
  val BlackBerry = """.*BlackBerry.*""".r
  val WAPBrowser = """.*(MIDP|UP\.Browser|Obigo|Polaris|BREW|Brew|NetFront).*""".r

  var platform = "UnknownPlatform"
  var platformVersion = "UnknownVersion"

  ua match {
    case iOS(_, version) => {
      platform = "IOS"
      platformVersion = version.replace("_", ".")
    }
    case Android(version) => {
      platform = "Android"
      platformVersion = version
    }
    case WindowsPhone() => platform = "WindowsPhone"
    case WebOS() => platform = "WebOS"
    case BlackBerry() => platform = "BlackBerry"
    case WAPBrowser(p) => platform = "WAPBrowser"
  }
}
```

Which can be tested with (simplified) code:

```
val tests = for (
    str <- List("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7",
      "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-us; Nexus One Build/FRF91) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1",
      "bla bla Windows Phone OS bla bla",
      "bla bla webOS bla bla",
      "bla bla BlackBerry bla bla",
      "LG-LX600 Polaris/6.0 MMP/2.0 Profile/MIDP-2.1 Configuration/CLDC-1.1")
  ) yield new UserAgent(str)

tests foreach { ua => println(ua.platform + " " + ua.platformVersion) }
```

This is not very scala-ish, since my class `UserAgent` has mutable variables `platform` and `platformVersion`. What I would want to achieve is to have immutability, so to have something like a `trait` that defines `platform` and `platformVersion` and subclasses that would return different values. What I am missing is how to create a constructor which would instantiate and return such subclass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Tuple2`:

```
  val (platform, platformVersionOpt) = ua match {
    case iOS(_, version) => "IOS" -> Some(version.replace("_", "."))
    case Android(version) => "Android" -> Some(version)
    case WindowsPhone() => "WindowsPhone" -> None
    case WebOS() => "WebOS" -> None
    case BlackBerry() => "BlackBerry" -> None
    case WAPBrowser(p) => "WAPBrowser" -> None
  }

  val platformVersion = platformVersionOpt.getOrElse("UnknownPlatform")
```

Scala way is to create object with `unapply` method:

```
object UserAgent {
  val iOS = """.*(iPad|iPhone|iPod).*OS ([0-9_]+).*""".r
  val Android = """.*Android ([0-9.]+).*""".r
  val WindowsPhone = """.*Windows Phone OS.*""".r
  val WebOS = """.*webOS.*""".r
  val BlackBerry = """.*BlackBerry.*""".r
  val WAPBrowser = """.*(MIDP|UP\.Browser|Obigo|Polaris|BREW|Brew|NetFront).*""".r

  def unapply(ua: String): Option[(String, Option[String])] = ua match {
      case iOS(_, version) => Some("IOS" -> Some(version.replace("_", ".")))
      case Android(version) => Some("Android" -> Some(version))
      case WindowsPhone() => Some("WindowsPhone" -> None)
      case WebOS() => Some("WebOS" -> None)
      case BlackBerry() => Some("BlackBerry" -> None)
      case WAPBrowser(p) => Some("WAPBrowser" -> None)
      case _ => None
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
scala> val tests = List("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-us; Nexus One Build/FRF91) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1", "bla bla Windows Phone OS bla bla", "bla bla webOS bla bla", "bla bla BlackBerry bla bla", "LG-LX600 Polaris/6.0 MMP/2.0 Profile/MIDP-2.1 Configuration/CLDC-1.1")

scala> tests foreach {
     |   case UserAgent(p, v) => println(p + " " + v.getOrElse("UnknownVersion"))
     |   case _ => println("UnknownPlatform UnknownVersion")
     | }
IOS 4.0
Android 2.2
WindowsPhone UnknownVersion
WebOS UnknownVersion
BlackBerry UnknownVersion
WAPBrowser UnknownVersion
```

Answer (score 1):

one possible answer, using a `Tuple2` and an `Option[String]` for the version.
I also moved the regex to the companion object.

```
object UserAgent {
  val iOS = """.*(iPad|iPhone|iPod).*OS ([0-9_]+).*""".r
  val Android = """.*Android ([0-9.]+).*""".r
  val WindowsPhone = """.*Windows Phone OS.*""".r
  val WebOS = """.*webOS.*""".r
  val BlackBerry = """.*BlackBerry.*""".r
  val WAPBrowser = """.*(MIDP|UP\.Browser|Obigo|Polaris|BREW|Brew|NetFront).*""".r
}

class UserAgent(val ua: String) {
  import UserAgent._

  val (platform, version): (String, Option[String]) = ua match {
    case iOS(_, version) =>
      ("IOS", Some(version.replace("_", ".")))
    case Android(version) =>
      ("Android", Some(version))
    case WindowsPhone() => 
      ("WindowsPhone", None)
    case WebOS() => 
      ("WebOS", None)
    case BlackBerry() => 
      ("BlackBerry", None)
    case WAPBrowser(p) => 
      ("WAPBrowser", None)
  }
}
```